# Poor performance with RX 480 on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, graphics

I have installed RX 480 (by XFX) today and for some unknown reason the performance is abysmal. AMDGPU-PRO driver (16.60-379184) installed without a hint of any problem, I have added myself to video user group, rebooted, everything seemed perfect, but when I ran DiRT Rally, I got hardly 30 FPS at a MEDIUM setting. I tried another games and they all run unusually slowly - as if was still running my old GTX 460.

Do you guys PLEASE have any idea what might be the problem here?

These are my specs (taken from Steam system info):

```
Processor Information:
    CPU Vendor:  GenuineIntel
    CPU Brand:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         920  @ 2.67GHz
    CPU Family:  0x6
    CPU Model:  0x1a
    CPU Stepping:  0x4
    CPU Type:  0x0
    Speed:  2668 Mhz
    8 logical processors
    4 physical processors
    HyperThreading:  Supported
    FCMOV:  Supported
    SSE2:  Supported
    SSE3:  Supported
    SSSE3:  Supported
    SSE4a:  Unsupported
    SSE41:  Supported
    SSE42:  Supported
    AES:  Unsupported
    AVX:  Unsupported
    CMPXCHG16B:  Supported
    LAHF/SAHF:  Supported
    PrefetchW:  Unsupported

Operating System Version:
    Ubuntu 16.10 (64 bit)
    Kernel Name:  Linux
    Kernel Version:  4.8.0-46-generic
    X Server Vendor:  The X.Org Foundation
    X Server Release:  11804000
    X Window Manager:  Compiz
    Steam Runtime Version:  steam-runtime-beta-release_2016-12-05

Video Card:
    Driver:  ATI Technologies Inc. AMD Radeon (TM) RX 480 Graphics

    Driver Version:  4.5.13468 Compatibility Profile Context 16.60.3
    OpenGL Version: 4.5
    Desktop Color Depth: 24 bits per pixel
    Monitor Refresh Rate: 60 Hz
    VendorID:  0x1002
    DeviceID:  0x67df
    Revision Not Detected
    Number of Monitors:  1
    Number of Logical Video Cards:  1
    Primary Display Resolution:  1600 x 1200
    Desktop Resolution: 1600 x 1200
    Primary Display Size: 16,06" x 12,05"  (20,08" diag)
                                            40,8cm x 30,6cm  (51,0cm diag)
    Primary VRAM: 8192 MB

Sound card:
    Audio device: Realtek ALC1200

Memory:
    RAM:  22083 Mb

Miscellaneous:
    UI Language:  English
    LANG:  en_US.UTF-8
    Microphone:  Not set
    Steam Controller Cable and Base:  Not set
    Total Hard Disk Space Available:  211915 Mb
    Largest Free Hard Disk Block:  174146 Mb
    VR Headset: None detected
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not have the amdgpu-pro drivers but I noticed that for some reason my RX580 does not ramp up the clock an memory speed when i start to play a game and i need to manually ramp it up.

```
sudo su
```

this tells you what clock speed you are at, mine typically sits at 300 and 300

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/amdgpu_pm_info
```

This tells you if you are on auto or high

```
cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level
```

this forces your gpu to clock it self high... so you should run this before playing games

```
echo high > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level
```

now check to see if your clock speeds are any faster

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/amdgpu_pm_info
```

Enjoy your new performance

this sets the gpu back to default low clock speeds.. do this when you exit game

```
echo auto > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level
```

this to check and make sure you are on auto

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/amdgpu_pm_info
```

Answer (score -1):

The amdgpu-pro 16.60 driver doesn't officially support Ubuntu 16.04.  As of today, the 17.10 driver came out- this driver officially supports Ubuntu 16.04.2.

I have the RX 480 and have seen the same issues.  The 16.40 driver was passable.  The 16.60 driver was awful.  I'm about to find out of the 17.10 driver helps.  I'll follow up momentarily.

Comment: Save your time. I did a clean install of 16.04.2 yesterday with AMDGPU-PRO 17.10 and there was no improvement in performance.